# call function or modify something when true

Tags: vue.js

I have a state in pinia which is an empty array, I have an action which makes a fetch request and saves the data in the array, I still have a getter where I map the array with the elements and get the id of each value. In my component I have a ref where it is true or false if the id I am passing is found in the pinia getter, the problem is that the load getter is empty so it always returns false, how can I avoid this and check if it exists the id already when the getter returns the array with all the elements?, I solve it with a setTimeout but I don't think it's the best way

```
component

    const fav= ref()
    
    const getFavorites= async () => {
      landsStore.fetchUserFavorites()
      isFav.value = getFavoriteIds.includes(id)
    }
    
    onMounted(() => {
      getFavorites()
    })
    
    getFavoriteIds always returns an empty array

state

 elements = [],



getter
getFavoriteIds: (state) => {
    return state.elements.map((val) => val.id);
 },

action
fetchUserFavorites() {
    fetch(`....`)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then(data => { 
        elements.push(data)
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log( err);
      })
  }
```

Comment: That is a huge chunk of text. Do you mind narrowing it down to a few sentences with only the most important part?

Comment: Agreed with @kissu, I wouldn't even try to read. But just looking at the code, i think you are missing a "await" for your function.